# PHP session only displaying part of variable

Tags: php, session, variables

I'm having an issue where, when I save a variable in a session array, it only stores the first word. That is, if it's 'Company one', it would only save 'Company'.  The variable comes from a selection list:

```
function listCompany() {
    include 'includes/connection.php';

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT CompanyName FROM Portal.company ORDER BY CompanyName ASC");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($col1);

    ?>

    <select name="CompanyName">
    <?

    $blank = "";
    echo "<option value=" . $blank . ">  </option>";
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "<option value=" . $col1 . ">" . $col1 . "</option>";
    }

    ?>
    </select>
<?
}
```

Then stored in a session:

```
$_SESSION['NewOrder'] = $array2 = array(
    "CompanyName" => $_POST['CompanyName'],
```

When I echo the variable, I just get the first word.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: how you are echoing the variable?and what is the output?please mention

Comment: The HTML value needs to be enclosed in valid quotes (i.e. ' or "). The ones used to concatenate PHP strings don't count.

Comment: should be `echo '<option value="' . $col1 . '">' . $col1 . '</option>';` or better `echo "<option value=\"$col1\">$col1</option>";` you are missing the quote around your value, so the browser takes first word for value and ignores the rest.

Comment: debug the _POST array with `print_r` or `var_dump`.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the quotes around the value. It should be

```
echo "<option value=\"$blank\">  </option>";
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<option value=\"$col1\">$col1</option>";
}
```

In your code the HTML output will be

```
<option value=Company one>Company one</option>
              ^-----^ <-- this part is taken as value the rest 
                          after space is invalid HTML so gets ignored
```

It should be

```
<option value="Company one">Company one</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of this line,

```
echo "<option value=" . $col1 . ">" . $col1 . "</option>";
```

You didn't quote your `value` in single quotes. It should be,

```
echo "<option value='" . $col1 . "'>" . $col1 . "</option>";
```